# Draco encoder lossless, is it possible?

Tags: unity, 3d

I'm trying to use the [draco library](https://github.com/google/draco) in a Unity project. I've a lot of obj files with models of a person in different positions. When I encode these models with the `draco_encoder` command I obtain a lossy conversion, and a lot of parts of my original models get lost.

I tried to play around the parameters `-qp` and `-cl` in order to change the quantization and the compression level, but also with `qp` at its maximum and `cl` to its minimum some parts get lost.

[image: Draco test]

In this image the left model is the original one. The right model is the one converted with `draco_encoder` by using `cl` 0 and `qp` 21. As you can see some parts are missing.

Do you have any suggestion on how can I obtain a lossless (as lossless as possible) conversion?

Comment: Doe the draco library documentation say anything about it? Does it claim the compression is lossless or not? It's also worth mentioning in the beginning a few things about that library, so people unfamiliar with it can better understand the question.

Comment: Have you tried another method of compressions, like converting to vertex buffer and a applying generic compressor?

Comment: I don't see any lossless option. But my research is not conclusive, so I can't really add more than a comment to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for encoding](https://github.com/google/draco#encoding-tool) states:

> A value of 0 for the quantization parameter will not perform any
>   quantization on the specified attribute. Any value other than 0 will
>   quantize the input values for the specified attribute to that number
>   of bits.
>   
>   ... 
>   In general, the more you quantize your attributes the better
>   compression rate you will get. It is up to your project to decide how
>   much deviation it will tolerate. In general, most projects can set
>   quantization values of about 14 without any noticeable difference in
>   quality.

That is the key section to note because [quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_(image_processing)):

> is a lossy compression technique achieved by compressing a range of
>   values to a single quantum value. When the number of discrete symbols
>   in a given stream is reduced, the stream becomes more compressible.

In your example, you're using a `qp` factor of 21; the docs say quality begins to change noticeably at around a `qp` of 14, so it's not surprising that you're seeing errors. If you want to reduce the lossiness, you need to reduce your `qp` value. Theoretically, a `qp` of 0 would give you lossless compression. You may need to increase the compression level `cl` to compensate.

That being said, most lossy compression techniques need to discard *some* data in order to achieve any compression at all. It's possible that reducing the `qp` to zero will prevent compression errors, but increase the over size of the data set once encoded.

Comment: Indeed it always discard a lot of vertices... As far as I understand it, unfortunatelly draco doesn't allow a lossless compression...

Comment: @Pikalek what you wrote is actually incorrect. The lower the qp value, the greater the quantization and therefore the worse things look. 0 is a special case - it means that no quantization should be performed, so the mesh doesn't change in any way. 1 is the greatest level of quantization (things look their worst with that level of quantization).